# SQL: Create new table or have redundant columns

Tags: sql, database

I have 6 Tables: AJob, BJob, CJob, A, B and C.

- AJob has a n:1 dependency on A,
- BJob has a n:1 dependency on B and
- CJob has a n:1 dependency on C.

Except the dependencies the (A|B|C)Job tables are the same.

Should I create a new table "Jobs" and move all the same columns?
(I would have to keep extra care of the 1:1 dependency between "(A|B|C)Job" and "jobs" and of the entries in "Jobs" when deleting a "(A|B|C)Job" )

Or should I keep the design where every jobtable has the redundant columns?

(I would have to use "union" in a subquery to search and I don't know if its too much normalisation)

Which one is a better practice?

Comment: Why do you have three different job tables?

Comment: Because every special jobs has this one dependency to A, B or C and I want to keep the 1:1 relationship. I want to know if there is a better way than redudant columns

Comment: I would need to see the PK FK relationships between A,B,C and the "Jobs" table.  are there three different columns in JOBS for the FK relationships back to A,B,C?  I would also need to understand if these FK's are UNIQUE or not.  It seems B,C would be unique which makes B,C Join to Jobs 1:1 where as A to Jobs would not be unique.  I think what you have know is close to 4th normal form; where as de-normalizing it to 3rd normal form would give you some performance boosts and save some coding headaches at the cost of future flexibility. If the data reps the same "Entity" it should be the same tbl

Comment: A has a primary key and A-related stuff.
B has a primary key and B-related stuff.
C has a primary key and C-related stuff.

AJob has a primary key, A_id which is a FK to A and common columns cc1, cc2, cc3

BJob has a primary key, B_id which is a FK to B and common columns cc1, cc2, cc3

CJob has a primary key, C_id which is a FK to C and common columns cc1, cc2, cc3

My though was to put cc1, cc2 and cc3 into a table jobs with a primary key and put that primary key into AJob, BJob and CJob as a FK.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I question if that would give me any performance boost.

Comment: There's just too much here.  Picture of before /after plan and data DDL of all 6 tables may help.  Without understanding the entities themselves and purposes this is just too ambigious.  I'm fearful that merging JobA, JobB, and JobC could result in duplicate keys unless you add a "JobType" and a composite key of the ID and JobType.  Then when Joining to A you know to join on JobType 'A' and ID. etc.....   and is there a system need to present all JobA,JobB and JobC along with attribute data from A,B,C?  if not then why merge?  I've nothing else to add unless before/after pic and ddl provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same columns in multiple tables, you usually don't need multiple tables. Put in one table with a column to differentiate A, B or C...

Have a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization